# How to Create Xamarin.forms Master page use Mvvmcross 5.4

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, master-pages

I want to create app use master page, The IOS is open but have back icon as 
on android there not display the master and detail view.

On rootviewmodel as following:

```
public RootViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            ShowInitialMenuCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowInitialViewModelsAsync);
            ShowDetailCommand = new MvxAsyncCommand(ShowDetailViewModelAsync);
            ShowInitialMenuCommand.ExecuteAsync();
            ShowDetailCommand.ExecuteAsync();
        }
```

I want to know how to create master page use `mvvmcross 5.4`.

Comment: Check the MvvmCross Samples https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Playground/Playground.Core/Pages

Comment: when start with MvxContentPage it is correct, but when start with MvxMasterDetailPage it is blank on android.                                                                               [MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(MasterDetailPosition.Root)]
    public partial class RootPage :  MvxMasterDetailPage<RootViewModel>
    {
        public RootPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Master = new MasterPage();
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new DetailPage());
        }
    }